# Should I consolidate test cases across projects by using a common project in HP ALM?

Tags: manual-testing, hp-alm

Our vision is to have central storage of consolidated test cases across all departments and to store it as a separate project in [HP ALM](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/software-solutions/alm-software-development-testing/index.html). This would allow us to collect test cases across different projects and store it in a common project in HP ALM.
Is this a good approach and what pro's / cons will it give us?
Many projects are using BPT testing and some projects are  doing manual testing in HP ALM.

Comment: @HelpingHands - when the OP says they need HP ALM, mentioning a competing product is pointless at best. If the OP's organization has purchased HP ALM and requires them to use it, that's what the OP will use.

Comment: @KatePaulk -I see, I have deleted my comment..

Answer (score 1):

There is no staight-forward answer to your question but, here are a few guidelines that may help you choose the best approcah for your organisation.

1. Is having a consolidated test cases suite the most efficient method of managing test cases in the context of your organisation and projects undertaken? The reason it's important that you know the answer to this question is because many times while the testing team wants to have a consolidated test cases suite, the departments may be operating in silos which would result either in duplication, inconsistency or becomes unmanageable.
2. Assuming you have decided to consolidate test cases - Think how these test cases are going to be used in the future.

You can consolidate them based on:

- Different applications &  their functionality
- User roles if that is the dominating factor
- Business processes if it is a workflow is a dominating factor
- Or a combination of these.

Again, this differs from organisation to organisation and project to project depending on how the test cases are going to be used in the future.

Comment: Thanks a lot.What is the efficient technique in collecting testcases from one project to another?

Comment: I think HP QC & ALM allows you to just copy a bunch of test cases and paste where you need them. You may also be able to do that via the backend database but it may be complicated.

Comment: You Have suggested me an idea as test cases can be consolidated based on User roles.Could you please let me know what is meant by that.It would be really Interesting If you explain me further